# shiny module for regular read data (not triggered by new session

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinymodules

just ending to modularise my shiny app but i have a problem :
my app is running all day long and some user come to consult it via web browser.
i create a module to read csv and i call the module each 30 minutes by reactivetimer.
the problem is the callmodule is within the server and every new session trig my module and re-read the data.
before modularisation i put all my read.csv outside the server like here :
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

```
refreshTimer <- reactiveTimer(1800000)#1800000ms pour 30min; timer pour relancer une importation

######### serveur #######  
  
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  observe({ 
    refreshTimer()
    r$data<-callModule(module = module_import_CSV_30min, id = "module_import_CSV_30min")
  })
```

looking for a solution all night long but dont find it.
any supposition?
thanks

Comment: Is your app deployment containerised?

Comment: Hi limey, sorry i dont understand your question.

Comment: My app is running a normal rstudio and just launch app via runapp and specifiyng the port to use (5050) then all guys on my local network can acces to the app via my ip/port (rstudio connect server incomming). App is composed with ui.r server.r and many modules

Comment: @limey, i look for container (with using docker) and i can answers you, i dont use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi finaly i found "solution".
in fact we cant use a module to import data for all session.
we have to make it into a global.R on in server.R(outside the shinyserver). because modules can only called into shinyserver and every new session will call one more time the module.
thanks for help.